# Extending Date class in ruby

Tags: ruby, date, extension-methods

I want to extend Date class in ruby.Actually what I want to do is that add a method to Date class. Following is an example

I want to add 'my_simple_method' method to Date class

```
def my_simple_method 
 puts 'this is from my_simple_method'
end
```

after adding this users should be able to call this method as

```
date_obj = Date.parse('2010-07-01')
puts date_obj.my_simple_method
```

should print  'this is from my_simple_method'

thanks in advance

cheers

sameera

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Date
  def my_simple_method
    puts 'this is from my_simple_method'
  end
end
```

Comment: i'd remove `puts` (we should `return` that)

Comment: What if i want to manipulate an attribute? I have a custom class with an array attribute in it. Say class MyClass with arr array.
I want to be able to to this.
m = MyClass.new
puts m.custom_method
and this custom_method to return a sum of the ints in the array arr.
(I do not want the sum, but let's say I do. I can't do it with other methods)